# Python package BeautifulSoup installation error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, package

professional...
BeautifulSoup install error...ㅠㅠ 
my windows environment is 64bit..and python also 64bit, 3.8.2version
help me

Collecting BeautifulSoup
  Using cached BeautifulSoup-3.2.2.tar.gz (32 kB)

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'C:\Users\hoyou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\hoyou\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\BeautifulSoup\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\hoyou\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\BeautifulSoup\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\ESTsoft\CreatorTemp\pip-pip-egg-info-j79vzovk'
     cwd: C:\Users\hoyou\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\BeautifulSoup\
Complete output (6 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\hoyou\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\BeautifulSoup\setup.py", line 3
    "You're trying to run a very old release of Beautiful Soup under Python 3. This will not work."<>"Please use Beautiful Soup 4, available through the pip package 'beautifulsoup4'."
                                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Try this - ```pip install beautifulsoup4```

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/

Answer (score 0):

You should consider Anaconda if you're running on Windows: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/.

Beautifulsoup package: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/beautifulsoup4

The package management is much easier than just using the "vanilla" python.